# Why can you still modify a List<> when it has the "in" parameter modifier in C# 7.2

Tags: c#, c#-7.2

Earlier this week, C# 7.2 was released with the new feature of "in" parameter modifier see release notes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-2)

The details provided in the release notes are:"The in modifier on parameters, to specify that an argument is passed by reference but not modified by the called method."

There is not a lot of documentation out on this new feature yet, so I have been trying it out. Seems to work as expected for primitive types, and prevents access to object properties. However, for lists you can still call the methods to modify a List (i.e. Add, Remove, Reverse) and you can actually modify an element directly.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new List<int>();
        test.Add(5);
        Console.WriteLine(test[0]);
        TestMethod(test);
        Console.WriteLine(test[0]);
    }

    public static void TestMethod(in List<int> myList)
    {
        myList[0] = 10;
        myList.Add(7);
        myList.Remove(2);
    }
```

My question is, why can still modify collections when using the "in" parameter modifier?

Comment: You are not modifying myList, it always references the same List object.  You are modifying the *content* of the list.  Extra level of indirection.  That's why they call it a "reference type", the code would not be valid if it were a value type (struct).  The intention is to get a large struct passed by reference (ref) under the hood and ensure you can't accidentally change its members.  So it doesn't have to be copied back to the caller's struct.  It is not useful for reference types.  Formerly the recommendation was to not give a struct more than 4 members, that's relaxed by `in`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `in` modifier only restricts assigning to the reference, but the `List<T>` is still accessible and mutable. Basically it works like `ref readonly`.

You can't do `myList = new List<int>`.

Comment: I read the release notes in the link specified by the OP. I do not think what you are saying is the case. It is not to restrict the reference assignment. Sounds like it does not allow mutating the object. Basically it is like a readonly object. For a list, you can add items to it, but you cannot change any of its properties. This is what I gather

Comment: @CodingYoshi it was designed for new struct types.

Comment: @CodingYoshi for instance you can have it pass a struct that won't be copied.

Comment: @CodingYoshi On this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types) it is more clear that is a complement to the already existing `ref` and `out` keywords. There is not much use to using it on a reference type since a reference still needs to be copied but for performance sensitive code using structs larger than size of a reference it is useful.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you, I believe you are correct. The documentation in the release notes seems a bit ambiguous imo.

Comment: @mikez thanks for that link. Yes that clarifies it and most of my assumptions about its intent were true.

Comment: This begs a new question: is c# becoming more of a procedural language?

Answer (score 1):

These points from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types) really clarifies the intent of the `in` modifier:

> There are several ways in which the compiler ensures that the read-only nature of an in argument is enforced. First of all, the called method can't directly assign to an in parameter.

Ok so that means we cannot do this:

```
public void Something(in Point3D point1)
{
    point1 = new Point3D(); // not allowed
}
```

> It can't directly assign to any field of an in parameter.

Ok so that means we cannot do this as well:

```
public void Something(in Point3D point1)
{
    point1.X = 10; // not allowed
}
```

> In addition, you cannot pass an in parameter to any method demanding the ref or out modifier.

Ok so that means we cannot do below as well for obvious reasons because the method we are calling can set the reference which will break the above first rule:

```
public void Something(in Point3D point1)
{
    SomethingElse(ref point1); // not allowed
}

public void SomethingElse(ref Point3D pointAnother)
{}
```

> The compiler enforces that the in argument is a readonly variable. You can call any instance method that uses pass-by-value semantics. In those instances, a copy of the in parameter is created. Because the compiler can create a temporary variable for any in parameter, you can also specify default values for any in parameter.

So what I gather from the above is that you can pass a `List<T>` and the called method will be able to add items to it but it will not be able to assign another list to it or changes it's fields.

**In Conclusion**

> Why can you still modify a List<> when it has the “in” parameter modifier in C# 7.2

You are allowed to do that because you are not breaking any of the rules.

Comment: In my testing you can still modify the Fields and Properties of an object passed in, and those changes are reflected in the original instance passed in as well. This is confusing since the documentation does explicitly state, as you mentioned, that you CANNOT directly assign to any Field (I also tested Properties).

public void Something(in Point3D point1)
{
    point1.X = 10; // In my testing, this IS allowed. But why? 
}